# iOS Method Return Multiple Values NSDictionary

Tags: ios, methods, nsdictionary

I have a method that I call that calculates the Sunrise, Noon and Sunset for any given day. I pass the method the day date as a Julian.

The method need to return the three numbers or strings: Sunrise, Noon and Sunset.

I am trying to call it as follows:

```
ClassSolarCalculations *LINK = [[ClassSolarCalculations alloc] init];
NSString dateSunrise= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", [LINK CalculateSunrise: Julian]];
```

where the Method reads:

```
(NSDictionary *) CalculateSunrise: (double) Julian;

NSDictionary *returnTimes = [NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys: SunriseText, @"Sunrise", NoonText, "@Noon", SunsetText, @"Sunset", nil];
return returnTimes;
```

I can this approach to work to return a single value but would like to return all three in one go rather than fudge the solution by calling variants of the routine three times…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of things should be changed here:

1. method and variable names should start with lowercase letters and use camel case.
2. Rename your `CalculateSunrise:` method since it will return more values. Maybe `calculateSunTimes:`.
3. Since your method returns an `NSDictionary` you handling of the return needs to be different.

Try this:

```
ClassSolarCalculations *link = [[ClassSolarCalculations alloc] init];
NSDictionary *times = [link calculateSunTimes:julian];
NSString *sunrise = times[@"sunrise"];
NSString *noon = times[@"noon"];
NSString *sunset = times[@"sunset"];
```

Your method would be something like:

```
- (NSDictionary *)calculateSunTimes:(double)julian {
    // calculate the three values:

    return @{ @"sunrise" : sunriseText, @"sunset" : sunsetText, @"noon" : noonText };
}
```

Notice the use of modern Objective-C syntax.

Comment: That works perfectly and several lessons learnt. Many thanks EH